# whirr cdh install version control

Tags: hadoop, apache-whirr

How can we control the hadoop version being install on ec2 using whirr. I can see the we have the following two line is the config file

whirr.hadoop-install-function=install_cdh_hadoop
whirr.hadoop-configure-function=configure_cdh_hadoop

but how do we control what version to install?

CDH3 or CDH4?

Also, MVR1 or MVR2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how its done in 0.8.1

```
whirr.env.mapreduce_version=2   
whirr.env.repo=cdh4
```

This goes into your properties file.

Answer (score 0):

```
## Install CDH4 Yarn 
whirr.hadoop.install-function=install_cdh_hadoop
whirr.hadoop.configure-function=configure_cdh_hadoop
whirr.yarn.configure-function=configure_cdh_yarn
whirr.yarn.start-function=start_cdh_yarn
whirr.mr_jobhistory.start-function=start_cdh_mr_jobhistory
whirr.env.REPO=cdh4
whirr.env.MAPREDUCE_VERSION=2

## Install CDH4 MRV1
whirr.hadoop.install-function=install_cdh_hadoop
whirr.hadoop.configure-function=configure_cdh_hadoop
whirr.env.REPO=cdh4
```